# What happened to my comment?

Tags: support, comments

I'm a bit mystified, a few hours ago, I posted a comment on [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/266370/157639).  It's somehow gone; I don't remember deleting it.  I'm guessing someone flagged it as obsolete, but the response to my comment is still there somehow.  It currently looks like @MainMa is talking to an imaginary friend...

Was my comment deleted because it was rendered obsolete due to an answer change?  If so, why wasn't the response to my comment also deleted?  Was it an error?  Was it me and I totally forgot about it? Or was it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to the obsolete comments. I missed a few cleaning them up.